# Не обрабатывается форма php

Tags: php, форма

Сама форма

```
<form method="POST" action="messages.php" name="msg">

Сумма
<input type="number" name="sum"  class="input" required="required"><br>

Тип <select form="msg" name="type" required="required">
<option>нал</option>
<option>безнал</option>
</select><br><br>

Назначение <select form="msg" name="target" required="required">
<option>Транспорт</option>
<option>Еда</option>
<option>Личные нужды</option>
</select><br><br>

Заявка
<textarea class="area" form="msg" name="text" required="required"></textarea><br><br>
Комментарий к заявке
<input type="text" name="comment" required="required" class="input"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="tofin" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="принята">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="knopka">
</form>
```

Код обработки

```
if(isset($_POST['sum']) &
   isset($_POST['type']) &
   isset($_POST['target']) &
   isset($_POST['text']) &
   isset($_POST['comment']) &
   isset($_POST['tofin']) &
   isset($_POST['status'])){

  $sql = "INSERT INTO
            `messages`
          SET
            `login`='".$_COOKIE['login'].",
            `sum`='".$_POST['sum']."',
            `type`='".$_POST['type']."',
            `stats`='".$_POST['status']."',
            `target`='".$_POST['target']."',
            `text`='".$_POST['text']."',
            `comment`='".$_POST['comment'].",
            `tofin`=".$_POST['tofin'];
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

Этот участок кода пропускается и исполняется конечный else{}.
Может проблема где-то в названиях полей или метода? Я все просмотрел, но так ничего и не нашел.

Comment: достаточно `if ($_POST) { ...` ..... а у `type` и `target` нужно убрать  `form="msg"` они же итак в форме......из-за этого кстати..`($_POST['type']` и `($_POST['target']` не приходят... и у них желательно прописать `value` в `option`.............. а вообще научитесь открывать панель разработчика в браузера и смотреть, что отправляется... чтоб не гадать

Comment: Дело в том, что у вас вместо оператора логического И && используется оператор побитового И &

Comment: Но оно все равно не будет у вас работать, даже если `&&` поставите... из-за `form="msg"` как я писал выше.....

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону блоков:

```
<option>нал</option>
<option>безнал</option>

<option>Транспорт</option>
<option>Еда</option>
<option>Личные нужды</option>
```

по факту `target` и `type` приходят пустыми. Верный синтаксис на примере `type`:

```
<select form="msg" name="type" required="required">
    <option value="нал">нал</option>
    <option value="безнал">безнал</option>
</select>
```

Ну и проверку всё таки лучше через `&&` проводить.